# can we Throwing Exception to a specific method c#?

Tags: c#, exception

I've cascading drop downs in my c# winform application and i'm getting data from wcf service and filling the drop downs. I want if any exception occurs in my event handlers then i should be able to throw exception to a specified method.
Is that Possible? Any syntax for this?

something like this

```
MethodName(throw);
```

Comment: Syntax for this is simple Try&Catch. Nothing else beyond that is required in this situation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't throw an exception to a specific method. The exception always bubbles up the call stack.

You can handle an exception by calling another method. In that case, just pass the exception to it:

```
try
{
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ShowErrorToUser(ex);
}

private void ShowErrorToUser(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: and what if in that method i want to check which type of exception it is? like 4,5 Types

Comment: Something like this? `if (ex is SomeException) { ... }`

Comment: thanks. Learnt new word "is". didn't know it existed. thanks mate ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to do this. Exceptions are raised and (simplified) bubbling up the call stack. So it always has to be a method in the call hierarchy that catches the exception.

You will need to add a call to the method that should handle the exception in your `catch` blocks.